# Whence comes the phrase "sus à..." meaning "death to...?"

Tags: étymologie, histoire

I just learned this phrase from an *Astérix* comic and found it etymologically confusing. The only thing I can think of that's lexically similar is the past tense of *savoir*.

How did *sus à* come to mean *death to*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never explicitly did.

This ***[sus](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sus/2)*** cognates with ***sur*** and *des**sus*** so is close to 'over' or 'upon'.

***Sus à** l'ennemi !* literally means something like '(Let's raid) **upon** the enemy!'

Comment: Sus à l'ennemi = A l'attaque = *Charge !*

Comment: Ah that makes so much more sense. Simple, but great answer!